# passing parameters to BeginGetRequestStream

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I am using thread pool to call some asynchronous web request call for posting the data

I am calling RunWebAccess function in a for loop

```
public void RunWebAccess (string strdara, int inttype)
{
     HttpWebRequest req = 
         (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.test.com");           
     byte[] requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlvar);
     req.Method = "POST";
     req.ContentType = "text/xml";
     req.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;         
     IAsyncResult result = 
         req.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(ProcessResults), req);
}

private void ProcessResults(IAsyncResult result)
{ 
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result);
    postStream.Write(result., 0, postData.Length ;
    postStream.Close();
}
```

**ProcessResults** function is not working because it can not access the parameters.

The problem is I want to pass the parameters in ProcessResults function and write to stream.

As per code, I can not use global variable or read input in ProcessResults function.
(I want to pass the strdara,inttype in ProcessResults function)

Answer (score 2):

You could use lambda-notation for the callback, something like this:

```
public void RunWebAccess (string strdara, int inttype)
{
     HttpWebRequest req = 
         (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.test.com");           
     byte[] requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlvar);
     req.Method = "POST";
     req.ContentType = "text/xml";
     req.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
     IAsyncResult result = null;
     result = 
         req.BeginGetRequestStream(ar =>
         {
            Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result);
            postStream.Write(result., 0, postData.Length ;
            postStream.Close();
         }
         , req);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could send a new object, containing all the parameters that you want to pass to the callback. Like:

```
IAsyncResult result = req.BeginGetRequestStream(
    new AsyncCallback(ProcessResults),
    new Tuple<HttpWebRequest,byte[]>(req, postData));
```